# When on enter keypress is triggered by jquery my model is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using require.js with backbone.js to structure my app. In one of my views:

```
    define(['backbone', 'models/message', 'text!templates/message-send.html'], function (Backbone, Message, messageSendTemplate) {
    var MessageSendView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#send-message'),
        template: _.template(messageSendTemplate),
        events: {
            "click #send": "sendMessage",
            "keypress #field": "sendMessageOnEnter",
        },
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this,'render', 'sendMessage', 'sendMessageOnEnter');
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },
        sendMessage: function () {
            var Message = Message.extend({
                noIoBind: true
            });
            var attrs = {
                message: this.$('#field').val(),
                username: this.$('#username').text()
            };

            var message = new Message(attrs);
            message.save();

            /*
        socket.emit('message:create', {
            message: this.$('#field').val(),
            username: this.$('#username').text()
        });
        */

            this.$('#field').val("");
        },
        sendMessageOnEnter: function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                this.sendMessage();
            }
        }
    });
    return MessageSendView;
});
```

When keypress event is triggered by jquery and *sendMessage* function is called - for some reason Message model is undefined, although when this view is first loaded by require.js it is available. Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with require.js, however, I think you might need to save `Message`, which is being sent in as an argument, as an object variable.  So add `Message: Message,` to your code, and call `this.Message` instead of `Message`. See if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my inline comments:

```
sendMessage: function () {
        // first you declare a Message object, default to undefined
        // then you refrence to a Message variable from the function scope, which will in turn reference to your Message variable defined in step 1 
        // then you call extend method of this referenced Message variable which is currently undefined, so you see the point
        var Message = Message.extend({
            noIoBind: true
        });
        // to correct, you can rename Message to other name, e.g.
        var MessageNoIOBind = Message.extend ... 
        ... 
    },
```

Comment: It looks like you were right coderek, I did not realize Message object was referencing the new Message variable that overshadowed the Message argument in the anonymous function argument list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've bound `sendMessageOnEnter` as a `keypress` event handler somewhere else in your code. By doing this, you will change the context of `this` upon the bound event handler's function being called. Basically, when you call this.sendMessage(), `this` is no longer your MessageSendView object, it's more than likely the jQuery element you've bound the `keypress` event to. Since you're using jQuery, you could more than likely solve this by using $.proxy to bind your `sendMessageOnEnter` function to the correct context. Something like: (note - this was not tested at all)

```
var view = new MessageSendView();

$('input').keypress(function() {
  $.proxy(view.sendMessageOnEnter, view);
});
```

I hope this helps, here is a bit more reading for you. Happy coding!

[Binding Scopes in JavaScript](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/)

[$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)